# Trying to access active directory from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Is there's any way to check if the username and password exist in Active Directory using VB.NET?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19689/Working-with-Active-Directory-in-VB-NET this is probably the best article regarding this matter

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722407/check-if-user-exists-in-active-directory

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the PrincipalContext Class' ValidateCredentials Method:

```
Dim objPrincipalContext As New System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YourDomain")

Dim bolIsAuthenticated As Boolean = objPrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials("UserName", "Password")
```

Comment: I couldn't find AccountManagement in DirectoryServices